# Background of selection if Firefox Window is inactive

Tags: css, firefox

I can change colour of selected text (and background) in active window of Firefox by:

```
::-moz-selection{color: white; background: black;}
```

But after selection and switching to other application the background is gray. How to change the background-color (including transparent) of selection if window is inactive?

Comment: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=706209

Comment: Thank you. Well, this is embarrassing... "Status:NEW,  Reported: 6 years ago"... It means: no solution with CSS only.

Comment: 6 years ago is fairly recent though; people just haven't got around to working on it. No need for panic yet! There are also bugs with status NEW that have been open a bit longer... https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=7915

Comment: This second bug levels up nicely. $tooLong =new _20YearsAgo();